# How do I connect my RPI 2, to the internet through ethernet?

Tags: raspbian, ethernet, internet

How do I setup my Raspberry pi 2, to the Internet using Ethernet? I am using the latest raspbian image. Is there anyone that can give me a step by step tutorial on how to do this? I have a wifi extender with a Ethernet port connected to my raspberry pi, so my pi is not directly connected to my comcast router.

Comment: Assuming you have some sort of router at home (which provides DHCP services)  it is as simple as plugging one end of a network cable into the router and the other end into the Pi. If this does not apply in your case you will need to provide us with additional information.